# How does the grinder work?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

The tutorial mission on how to use the grinder machine is not very in-depth. It has you put in three of the same rarity weapons (in this case, white), and it gives you a better, blue gun.

Other than that it mentions that you have to experiment with different recipes and that if you grind with moonstone you are more likely to get better results.

I have tried the grinder quite a few times and sometimes I put in three weapons of the same rarity, and it does not allow me to grind them.

I have listed a number of specific questions, but would like to just know as much as possible about how exactly the grinder works.

1. What other requirements must be met in order for you to be able to grind weapons?
2. Is it just that some weapons don't mix, such as different elemental weapons?
3. Does the weapon class have anything to do with it (pistol, shotgun, etc.)?
4. Is it possible to grind purple weapons (or higher)?

Comment: You CAN get legendaries from the grinder. It's an achievement.

Comment: [It's being worked out](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WHidSfCNzO0Z9Mamd0_UBjudhrCZ_WOjxA-p0GzcOWo/htmlview?sle=true) at least, but I don't think it's completely understood at this time. More experimentation is needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Grinder), you need to input specific recipes into the grinder. The recipes, are as follows, and require items of the same rarity in every case but the legendary case:

- **Legendary of desired type**: 2 legendary weapons + 1 purple weapon of the desired type
- **Up one rarity level (specific type)**: 2 weapons of the desired type + 1 other weapon
- **Up one rarity level (any type)**: 3 weapons of different types
- **Up one rarity level (non-weapons)** 3 items of same type (grenade mod, shield, etc)
- **Assault Rifle**: 1 SMG + 1 Sniper Rifle + 1 Shield
- **Rocket Launcher**: 2 weapons of any type + 1 Grenade Mod
- **Shotgun**: 1 Pistol + 1 SMG + 1 Shield
- **SMG**: 1 Assault Rifle + 1 Pistol + 1 Shield
- **Sniper Rifle**: 1 Assault Rifle + 1 Shotgun + 1 Shield

For all except the legendary recipe, these recipes work for anything up to and including blue inputs, with the potential to output a weapon of the same rarity or greater. If fed moonstones, the grinder will always output an item of increased rarity, and has a chance to add a luneshine effect to the weapon.

Answer (score 4):

What I've experienced thus far was that the weapons must be the same quality and the same weapon type (AR, SMG, pistol, etc). I don't believe the manufacturer or the element has any effect on the outcome.

About mixing purples; I have not been able to grind 3 purples together as of now. Maybe its to allow players to progress further into the game before implementing it so as to not exploit it to gain legendary weapons early on, however there is an achievement for it so I believe it will let you at one point.

Comment: See, I've been able to combine unlike weapons as far as types go. It depends on the combination though.