# Why can't I grind my three Purple Shields?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I have 3 Purple Shields, and I tried to grind them. None of them are Mission Rewards.

Is it because one of them was from grinding three Legendary Shields, and so it technically isn't of the same rarity?

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188171/how-does-the-grinder-work)

Comment: @Unionhawk - Hmm. Yeah, that question is pretty general and incomplete, given that it doesn't hold all the Wiki's info. Along with this peculiarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems to be the case. Swapping out the Legendary-derived Purple for one derived from Blues made it work.

And that Legendary Purple can be ground with actual Orange Legendaries.